# Vertical Alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please take a look at this: http://sources.freehosting.bg/landing.html

I am trying to vertically align #content so it looks good on larger (1920x1200) and smaller (1024x768) resolutions. By that I mean it does not have a scrollbar.
As you see there is plenty of free space so a scrollbar is unneeded.

The only solution I came up with is to calculate the height of #content with JS and to set a padding, but I realize it is the lamest possible solution.

Please advise me on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

See if **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a12jun/G96nG/)** is what you are looking for.  Simple solution IMO.

It works by forcing the containing `div` to behave as a `table-cell`, and making use of the `vertical-align: middle` style.  It doesn't require you to know the heights of any elements at all.

Code used in the fiddle are below.

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    text inside div a
    <div class="b">
        text inside div b
    </div>
</div>
```

The important styles are:

```
display: table-cell 
vertical-align: middle
```

The rest are only there for demonstration. CSS:

```
div.a {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
div.b {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 200px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your content height is fixed put a div before the content

```
<div id="distance"></div>
<div id="content">
  Vertically centered :D
</div>
```

and style it like:

```
html, body {
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

div#distance {
width:1px;
height:50%;
margin-bottom:-300px; /* half of website height */
float:left;
}

div#content {
text-align:left;
margin:auto;
position: relative;
width: 950px;
height: 600px;
clear: left;
}
```

​

Comment: For this to work I still need to calculate the height of the dark grey space with JS and to set the #content to that height. Then I have to wrap the #content inner elements in some div and to apply your technique to that div. Again it uses JS :)

Comment: Not really. You can just have the grey background and wrap all this in a div which is 100% height. After said div, you put the footer and give it a negative top margin to move it back into view. All you have to know is how high is your footer and how high is your main content (e.g. the handwritten stuff + what's between the horizontal lines).

Comment: I have updated the html and css. Please take a look.
I wrapped the #content inner elements into a "div.inner" and set the height of #content to 100%. Nothing happened. As clearly I don't understand what you mean, can you apply the example on the site I am showing?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of that works using pure CSS, no JS and no hacks requires you to know the height of the thing you're trying to position:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* Give your document height */
      body, #content {
        height: 100%;
      }

      /* Give your element height */
      .thing {
        width: 20px;
        height: 300px;
        background: #000;
      }
      /* Position thing */
      #content .thing {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -150px; /* half the height of the thing */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
       <div class="thing"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Updated height of item, container id.  Still works just fine.

Comment: The height of the thing I am trying to position is 300px, BUT in order  of that to work, I need to expand the container (which is not "body", but #content) in height. Which has to be done with JS in my opinion.

Comment: Your opinion doesn't matter.  My opinion doesn't matter.  What matters is "does the code work?"  Copy the code, enter it into any editor and see if it works with your own eyes.

Comment: I know it works but that is not my case.
In my case the #content does not expand over the whole gray area, which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do this without javascript and without knowing the height of the content - but purists will not like it. Then again, sometimes it doesn't matter if it's not approved by the trendy people. Sometimes all you need is to get the job done because you boss wants it that way.

And the solution is: **use a table** (told you purists wouldn't like it). Do layout the old school way and abuse the fact that HTML specifies lots of capabilities to tables.

A table cell is the only HTML element that has a vertical alignment attribute that does what most people expect it to do. Just give the table 100% width and height (so that is expands with the window size) and use cell alignment to position the content you want.

I've only ever had to use this trick once and it still makes me feel dirty* but when you really need it it works better than anything else.

**note: I'm a purist myself but understand that sometimes a man's got to do what a man's got to do.*